# TypeError: 'set' object is not callable in delete request of python requests module

Tags: python

I am trying to delete git hub files with remote api, I am able to do in curl but i don't know how to do in python here is what i tried and i am getting the

> 500 internal server TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

```
@app.route("/getFiles/delete/<id>", methods=['DELETE'] )
def deleteFile(id):
   auth = ('user','password')
   url = "https://api.github.com/repos/"+userName+"/"+repoName+"/contents/"+id;
   data={"message" : "my commit message", "sha":"9daeafb98644862175ae93beb0afd6c7d144bfa4"} 
   response = requests.delete( url, auth=auth, json=data )
```

Comment: try `response = requests.delete( url, auth=auth, json=data )` instead `response = requests.delete( url, auth=auth, data=data )` because `data` param expects dictionary or list of tuples, `json` param is meant for json data (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#main-interface)

Comment: still getting the same error after trying **response = requests.delete( url, auth=auth, json=data )**

Comment: you omitted the declaration/initialization of the auth variable. is it possible that auth is a set (instead of a tuple)?

Comment: thanks @Fabian changed the **auth = {'user' ,'password'} to auth = ('user', 'password')** and it worked. Now i am able to delete the file in git hub but there is a error showing **ValueError: View function did not return a response** is there any way to avoid this i have updated the code please check it

Comment: @Jazz actually return a response?

Comment: thanks after adding a return statement now its ok